# How to arrange 15 women and 15 men so no two females are seated next to each other?

Tags: probability, permutations

To a certain conference, each firm can send two employee representatives, on the condition that one of them is a male and the other a female. If 15 firms were represented in this conference, what is the probability that no two females are seated next to each other? (Assume that all 30 members are seated in a single row of seats)
A] 1/2
B] 14!/30!
C] 15!/30!
D] 28/30!

For above question I am trying following: 15 men can be arranged in 15! ways. There are 16 spots among men (-M-M-.....-M-). 16 spots can be taken by 15 women in 16! ways. My answer is (15!*16!)/30!. But it's not listed in answer choices. Am I missing something or answers are incorrect?

My approach is similar to approach in question in below link. 
[How many ways are there for 10 women and six men to stand in a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588083/how-many-ways-are-there-for-10-women-and-six-men-to-stand-in-a-line)

Comment: Your analysis is correct.

Comment: You are welcome. I thought for a while about what strange interpretation of the wording could make one of the proposed answers correct, but could not come up with one. I would probably instead say there are $\binom{30}{15}$ equally likely ways to choose the positions for the women, of which $\binom{16}{15}$ are "favourable." Divide, same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ If we can represent man by $\bf{M}$ and Women by $\bf{W}$, Then we use Gap Method.

So Arrangements as $$_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_$$

Above $15$ man can be arrange as $15!$ (Here Man and women all are Different)

Now We can Arrange $15$ Women in These $16$ Gap, Which can be done by $\displaystyle \binom{16}{15}\times 15! = 16!$

So Total no. of Arrangement in which no $2$ woman sit together is $\displaystyle 15! \times 16!$

And Total Probability $\displaystyle = \frac{\bf{Favourable \; cases}}{\bf{Total \; Cases}} = \frac{15!\times 16!}{30!}$

So I Think Your answer is Right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is wrong because it doesn't take in account that two men can seat side by side (if you have tow women on te exterior) : WMWMWM..WMMW

Something like ${30*15!*15!\over30!}$

Comment: The proposed solution is correct.  Note that if no two women sit next to each other, they must fill one of the $14$ spaces between adjacent men or the two spaces at the ends.  If both spaces at the ends are filled, one of the spaces between adjacent men does not contain a woman, so those two men do sit next to each other.